# Navbar Options not appearing always the Navbar

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have my own [website](http://campusconnect.cc)

However, on resizing it, I see the options on the navbar going up and down, depending on window size, what is the problem? How do I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple fix is to change the `.container` to a `.container-fluid`:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header navbar-right">
    ...
    </div>
</div>
```

This will resize the container and not make it have fixed width.